# Use parameter in other Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures, global-variables

Im creating an agent job whos looking in my table for an xml-string. If there is an xml string which not already have been run. I want to save it as variable, parameter or something so that i can use it to Merge into my other table. How can i save xml string as any type of variable so that i can get/use it in my other Query.

```
DECLARE @XmlDocument AS xml;
SET @XmlDocument = (SELECT TOP 1 XMLData FROM dbo.Integration WHERE Entity = 'Currency' and [Status] = '0');
```

I have been looking on stored procedure but i cant get it to work, if thats a good way of doing it i would really appreciate a good explaination.

EDIT 2: This is my other query i want to import the variable into.

```
Create Table #TempTable(IntComp NVARCHAR(100), Active NVARCHAR(100), Currency NVARCHAR(100), [Text] NVARCHAR(100))
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @XmlDocument AS xml;
SET @XmlDocument = '';
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://Bla.Bla.Currency' AS ns0)
INSERT INTO #TempTable (IntComp, Active, Currency, [Text])      
            SELECT 
                    @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/IntComp[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') IntComp,
                    @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/Active[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') Active,
                    @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/Currency[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') Currency,
                    @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/Text[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') [Text]                  
MERGE #TempTable AS T
USING dbo.etCurrency AS S
ON (T.IntComp = S.IntComp and T.Currency = S.Currency)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET T.IntComp = S.IntComp, T.Currency = S.Currency
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
VALUES(S.IntComp, S.Active, S.Currency, S.Text);
UPDATE dbo.Integration
    SET [Status] = '1' WHERE [Status] = '0';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
UPDATE dbo.Integration
    SET [Status] = '99', [StatusMessage] = @@ERROR WHERE [Status] = '0';
END CATCH
DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

Comment: What is the problem which you are getting with your current query? It looks good to me

Comment: The problem is i cant use the variable in my other Query. I want to save a Variable in this query and use it in my other query if possible.

Comment: Can you show how you are using the variable in your other query?

Comment: Right now im not using it, since i dont know how. But i posted my other query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to create a stored procedure with that SQL in it? If so, how about;

```
create procedure dbo.MyProcedure (@XmlDocument XML)
as
begin

    Create Table #TempTable(IntComp NVARCHAR(100), Active NVARCHAR(100), Currency NVARCHAR(100), [Text] NVARCHAR(100))
    BEGIN TRY
        WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://Opto.Schemas.Currency' AS ns0)
        INSERT INTO #TempTable (IntComp, Active, Currency, [Text])      
                    SELECT 
                            @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/IntComp[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') IntComp,
                            @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/Active[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') Active,
                            @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/Currency[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') Currency,
                            @xmldocument.value('/ns0:Currency[1]/Currency[1]/Text[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') [Text]                  
        MERGE #TempTable AS T
        USING dbo.etCurrency AS S
        ON (T.IntComp = S.IntComp and T.Currency = S.Currency)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET T.IntComp = S.IntComp, T.Currency = S.Currency
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
        VALUES(S.IntComp, S.Active, S.Currency, S.Text);
        UPDATE dbo.Integration
            SET [Status] = '1' WHERE [Status] = '0';
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE dbo.Integration
            SET [Status] = '99', [StatusMessage] = @@ERROR WHERE [Status] = '0';
    END CATCH

    DROP TABLE #TempTable;

end
```

Then to call it you would use;

```
DECLARE @XmlDocument AS xml;
SET @XmlDocument = (SELECT TOP 1 XMLData FROM dbo.Integration WHERE Entity = 'Currency' and [Status] = '0');
EXEC dbo.MyProcedure @XmlDocument
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by using stored procedure:

```
create procedure getXML
@xml XML 
as
select XMLData
from dbo.Integration
where Entity = 'Currency' and [Status] = '0';
Go
```

And then calling this stored procedure by :

```
declare @xml XML
exec getXML @xml
```